# Improving performance of EXTRACTVALUE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, xml, performance, oracle, plsql

Is there any possibility to improve performance of this query in PL/SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(body),'/Event/Description/Status') = 'Cancelled'
```

When `EXTRACTVALUE` is in `WHERE` clause, whole query executes 15 seconds, definitely too long.

When `EXTRACTVALUE` is used in select statement like this

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(body),'/Event/Description/Status') FROM events
```

it takes only 0.5 second.

Column `body` is CLOB type.

Comment: The first query might include the CLOB in select list whereas the second query just has one column to select from. How long does the 1st query take, if you replace the asterisk with "EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(body),'/Event/Description/Status')" (as in the 2nd query)? And how big is your CLOB?

Comment: If I replace it as you said, results are the same (even a bit longer). My CLOB are very different, some have 600 lines, some 10000 lines, but selecting the `Status` value was quick, so I didn't thought that filtering by that would increase execution time so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions aren't slower in the WHERE clause.  But it may appear that way if your IDE only returns the top N rows.

You can probably improve performance with a function based index.

Here's the sample table and data.  Only one out of 1000 rows contains the status "Cancelled", making it a good candidate for an index.

```
create table events(id number primary key, body clob);

insert into events
select level,
    '<Event>
        <Description>
            <Status>'||
            case when mod(level, 1000) = 0 then 'Cancelled' else 'Active' end||
            '</Status>
        </Description>  
    </Event>'
from dual connect by level <= 10000;

commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'EVENTS');
end;
/
```

The query takes 3 seconds to perform a full table scan.

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(body),'/Event/Description/Status') = 'Cancelled';
```

Creating an index changes changes the plan to an INDEX RANGE SCAN, and reduces the
time to 0.03 seconds.

```
create index events_fbi on events
    (extractValue(xmltype(body), '/Event/Description/Status'));

SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(body),'/Event/Description/Status') = 'Cancelled';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build a materialized view:

```
create view x as
  select
      e.*, 
      EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(body),'/Event/Description/Status')  status
    FROM events e;

create materialized view x2 as select * from x;
```

Then select from the materialized view. To speed things up, you could put an index on the status column.